# Is erlang mnesia db suitable to save millions or more records?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I wonder whether mnesia db is suitable to save million or more records or not?

1. because mnesia's storage place has only 3, `ram, disc_only, disc`. It is not possible to save part of records in ram. I suspect that if I select `disc` for storage and record's quantity is huge, ram buffer efficiency is very low, and if `disc_only` for storage and speed is also slow.

So in every situation, it is not correct choice to save many record, is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mnesia is not so bad but...

you can read here why mnesia suxs not:
http://noss.github.com/2009/04/04/mnesia-sucks-not.html

And here is answer to your question:
[Very Large Mnesia Tables in Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090193/very-large-mnesia-tables-in-production)